# How can i shorten name of interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

suppose i imported a namespace in typescript , lets call it `ui` , and it has one more namespace called `dates` and then there is one interface called `IDateFormat`, but only `ui` is exported

so if I have to consume the interface i have to do

```
import {ui} from '..pathToFile'

//to use interface i have to do
const format : ui.dates.IDateFormat
```

so basically i have to write `ui.dates.IDateFormat` every time

can i shorten it by assigning to a variable.

like

```
const intrface : < what's the type> = ui.dates.IDateFormat; // will this work
```

and use it

but i was thinking what will be the type of such variable and is there any other way to do it?

Comment: export the `IDateFormat ` interface directly?

Comment: `type IShort = ui.dates.IDateFormat;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [type alias](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases). It doesn't use a `const` declaration:

```
type Intrface = ui.dates.IDateFormat;

const format : Intrface = …;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just export it from your own module like this:

```
export type shortType = ui.dates.IDateFormat;
```

```
export interface shortInterface extends ui.dates.IDateFormat {

}
```